# Pass function for child with unknown parameter in Angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 component (Brand, Product) with pagination and search.
So, I want to create reuse paginator. This paginator component receive

```
@Input() currentPage: number;
@Input() totalPage: number;
```

Now, I have (3: current, 6: total)

```
1, 2, [3], 4, 5, 6
```

When change page, it call function from parent component like

```
this.getAllProduct(currentPage, totalPage);
```

But when I search with pagination, function search in brand(product) component look like

```
searchBrand(name);
```

or

```
searchProduct(name, sku, brand, category, price, ....);
```

How to pass this function for child component (paginator), when I click page, it call these function

Comment: Can't u do it with simple @Output? send an event from paginator  to parent?

Comment: Tks @Plochie, I used `@Output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has this documentantation page with examples and explanations about how to make your components interact. Read it thoroughly, it will give you all the tools you need: [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

To answer to this specific question:

- If the action originates in the parent, and you want to invoke a method that exists in the children, either use [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) or [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

  - With `@Input` you can listen for changes in the child by implementing the [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) method.
  - With `@ViewChild` you can invoke a child's method directly from the parent. This is for more advanced uses, so I doubt you want this for this case.
- If the action originates in the child, and you want to invoke a method that exists in the parent, then use [`@Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output).

For more advanced use cases, you can use a service to communicate both parent and child bidirectionally.

Comment: It worked, tks @MondKin. Follow guide from angular doc and done!!